# Rectangle not appearing in js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas, rect

I have a devastating problem that I can't fix. 

The JS canvas is screwing up a rectangle next to a player function expression.Here is the player code:

```
var menuSwitch = 0;
var pocx = 210;
var pocy = 20;
var switch1;
var lvlSwitch = 1;
var spd = 10;
var mx,my;
var pl = pl();
function pl(){
return{
    draw: function(){
        //draw the player
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);//clears so the player doesn't "drag"
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.arc(pocx, pocy, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        //move the player
        if(switch1 == 0){
            pocx = 210;
            pocy = 20;
        }else if(switch1 == 1){
            pocy -= spd;
        }else if(switch1 == 2){
            pocx -= spd;   
        }else if(switch1 == 3){
            pocy += spd;
        }else if(switch1 == 4){
            pocx += spd;
        }

        //rect bounding the player
        if(pocx < 5){//since half of the diameter of the player is 5, the edge of the circle "bounces"
            switch1 = 4;
        }
        if(pocy < 5){
            switch1 = 3;   
        }
        if(pocx > w){
            switch1 = 2;
        }
        if(pocy > h){
            switch1 = 1;
        }
    }
};
}
```

The canvas is 420 by 420. The `paint()` function, which goes 30 milliseconds each time by a `setInterval` is displayed here:

```
function paint(){
//pl.draw();
if(menuSwitch == 0){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,380,50);
    ctx.font = 'normal 30pt Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
    ctx.fillText("Math Path",105,60);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
    ctx.fillRect(105,150,210,25);//105+210=315
    ctx.font = 'normal 15pt Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
    ctx.fillText("Start",170,170);
}
if(menuSwitch == 1){
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(300,20,120,20);
pl.draw();

}
}
```

However, I'm focusing on the place where `menuSwitch == 1` in the if statement. You can see that I'm calling the player. The player shows up, but not the rectangle. Please help? :(

Useful link: [Canvas Tutorial](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/)

Html code if you need it:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tdnm03v/17/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you call `ctx.fillRect(300,20,120,20);` in the player function. Fo fix it, remove that line and add it to your paint function like:

```
function paint() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h); //clears so the player doesn't "drag"
    //pl.draw();
    if (menuSwitch == 0) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
        ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 380, 50);
        ctx.font = 'normal 30pt Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
        ctx.fillText("Math Path", 105, 60);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
        ctx.fillRect(105, 150, 210, 25); //105+210=315
        ctx.font = 'normal 15pt Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
        ctx.fillText("Start", 170, 170);
    }
    if (menuSwitch == 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        pl.draw();
        ctx.fillRect(300, 20, 120, 20);
    }
}
```

Fiddle showing example: https://jsfiddle.net/22w9j3p0/

Answer (score 0):

It's because your player function clears canvas and this means that you draw rectangle, then you clear everything and draw player. To fix it you can choose several solutions:

1. Move your `pl.draw()` 2 lines up
2. Move `clearRect` to `paint` function on the first line (I recommend to use this option)
3. Uncomment your commented line with `pl.draw` and comment uncommented `pl.draw`. It also should fix the problem.

Anyway be careful with order of drawings. `clearRect` should go first, and all the rest drawing will be drawn by their order. So if you want to draw rectangle above the circle (for example), you should write code drawing circle above the code of rectangle.